# FetchError: request to https://rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000/v1/locales failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED fe80::9030:9b22:8639:bfb3:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I am working on one windows application where one layer is built on top of Node.js where we basically calling one language API to get the list of languages.
Earlier when we were using Node v16.14.2, node-fetch -: 3.2.9, OS -: Windows10. It was working fine. But recently I only upgraded node from v16.14.2 to v18.5.0.
Now I am calling language API to get list of languages and it's not working and getting below error

```js
FetchError: request to https://rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000/v1/locales failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED fe80::9030:9b22:8639:bfb3:3000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/ASHISH_BUTOLA/broker/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:465:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}
```

Here is my code which I tried.

```js
    import fetch from 'node-fetch';
    import { Agent } from 'https';
    import { certificates } from '@self-trend/v2-util'; // private npm to get certificates
    
    async function getSupportedLanguages (payload) {
        let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "user-agent":"broker v4.7.1",
                "content-type":"application/json",
                }
        }
        const isSecure = true // isSecure = false in cloud mode
        if (isSecure) {
            options.agent = new Agent(await getAgentOptions());
        }
        // Language API to get list of languages. 
        const url = 'https:///rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000/v1/locales'
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, options)
            console.log(`Options is ****${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    async function getAgentOptions () {
        const certs = await certificates.list();
        const agentOptions = {
          ca: [certs.root],
          cert: [certs.client],
          key: [certs.clientKey]
        };
    
        return agentOptions;
    }
```

So We basically call getSupportedLanguages function then inside it calling languages API to get list of languages. Do I need to add some extra params to agentOptions to make it work with v18.5.0 or something else in above code. Because above API works fine with Node(v18.5.0) in cloud where we don't add agents or certificate with HTTPS request.
So I think might be something missing with agents. But not sure. I tried with different node-fetch version but still not working. I called a public API(https://api.publicapis.org/entries) just to test if other API's are invoked or not. So Public API is working fine with Node(v18.5.0). Not able to figure out why languages API(https:///rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000/v1/locales) is not working with Node(v18.5.0)

Comment: what about `https://rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000/v1/locales` - does that work?

Comment: Yes It works with Node(v16.14.2) but when I upgrade from Node(v16.14.2) to Node(v18.5.0). Get above mentioned error in Catch block

Comment: I take it `rf-werf.rdvd.com` is some local thing?

Comment: Yes. It's local Windows Virtual machine. This is a windows application. So set up Application on Winodws virtual machine. 'rf-werf.rdvd.com' Windows Virtual machine Host

Comment: well, whatever is running on port 3000 on that machine, it's not accepting connections - in other words, it's the server that is the issue

Comment: But It takes request when I hit API from Node(v16.14.2) but not with Node(v18.5.0)

Comment: perhaps you haven't re-allowed node to serve incoming connections in windows firewall - different version of nodejs, windows probably isn't allowing it

Comment: I re allowed the node to serve incoming request. But Still not working. Is there any possibility that 'rf-werf.rdvd.com' server which is built on top of python accepts request from only node server where (Node version <= v16)

Comment: absolutely no reason for that at all since the server would have no clue what is making the request - oh wait, the nodejs isn't the server ... sorry, I assumed

Comment: Because we are calling other server which is running on 4242(rf-werf.rdvd.com:4242). This server is working fine with Node(v18.5.0). Problem is only with 'rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000' this server. That's why I am thinking ('rf-werf.rdvd.com:3000') is allowing only <= Node(v16). But not sure

Comment: Found the issue. Actually Node18 is favouring IPV6 and server which is running on 3000 is accepting only IPV4 request. That's why server was accepting request from Node16 because Node16 is requesting IPV4 request but Node18 is sending IPV6. We allowed server to accept both(IPV4 as well as IPV6) request. Working Now. Thank you.